# pycharm .run not showing i have been facing this issue for no matter what i do its not changing

Tags: python, mod-python

```
 File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\calculator\calc.py", line 19, in <module>
    calc.run
AttributeError: 'Calculator' object has no attribute 'run'
```

This is the problem i have been facing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc = Calculator()

    calc.run
```

Here Is the code which is showing error

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory. Apparently your `Calculator` class doesn't have an attribute named `run`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.